# How to compare folding, powerline and mkview?

Tags: vim

I`m using following VIM settings for folding:

```
highlight Folded guibg=black guifg=#524A4D
set foldmethod=syntax
```

I`m also using Powerline plugin:

```
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'
```

I would like to save my foldings, so i found this two lines of code:

```
au BufWinLeave * silent! mkview
au BufWinEnter * silent! loadview
```

But after that my powerline status vanish after saving.
How to compare this three things.

I created screencast to show exactly whats going on:
http://screencast.com/t/ZnXTxdAVUZse

I think it is conflict between Powerline and mkview. So is then a chance to save foldings in other way??

Comment: Did Vim crash (then: version, OS, etc.?), or did the statusline stop updating / vanish / ??? If the latter, did you report this problem to the powerline plugin author?

Comment: Sorry, only statusline vanish. Yes, I created issue in powerline repo on github. I`m waiting for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a answer:

```
set viewoptions-=options
augroup vimrc
    autocmd BufWritePost *
    \   if expand('%') != '' && &buftype !~ 'nofile'
    \|      mkview
    \|  endif
    autocmd BufRead *
    \   if expand('%') != '' && &buftype !~ 'nofile'
    \|      silent loadview
    \|  endif
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

[The issue you have created on Github](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/issues/172) is likely to be more useful than this question here but I think your issue could be related to [this other one](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/issues/28).

You should remove the `highlight Folded guibg=black guifg=#524A4D` from your vimrc and delete the session files.

Comment: nope, I removed it and deleted session files but it not help with this issue.

Comment: I think it is conflict between Powerline and mkview. So is then a chance to save foldings in other way??